# Jxls Error : Cannot load XLS transformer. Please make sure a Transformer implementation is in classpath

Tags: java, excel, jxl, jxls

This question has been already asked once but no one gave a absolute solution to it.
Im trying to generate a xls file from a existing template but im getting an error which I dont know how to face out!

My code:
String nombre = "Manuel";

```
        try (InputStream templateFileName = ExportExcelServlet.class.getResourceAsStream("/segJBOSS/lib/xls/Tabla_Gestion.xlsx")) {
            try (OutputStream destFileName = new FileOutputStream("Tabla_Gestion.xls")) {
                ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
                array.add(nombre);
                Context context = new Context();
                context.putVar("gestion", array);
                JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(templateFileName, destFileName, context);              
                } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();                
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is being implemented into a WebServlet.

```
17:08:43,472 ERROR [org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory] (default task-3) Method createTransformer of org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer class thrown an Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

17:08:43,478 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) Cannot load XLS transformer. Please make sure a Transformer implementation is in classpath
17:08:43,479 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3) java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load XLS transformer. Please make sure a Transformer implementation is in classpath
```

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you have *jxls-poi* and Apache POI jars in the classpath (if you plan to use Apache POI)

Comment: Yes I have installed all the needed files, do you think that it might have to do with the template file location?

Comment: No, I do not think it is related to template location. Can you also post the full error stack trace?

Comment: Solved. It had to do with the maven dependecies installation.

Comment: I added and extra dependencies making it overcollapse. Thanks anyways

Comment: @LorenzoGamboa what were the extra dependencies? Could you show a pom file?

Comment: I'm not the OP but the answer provided the correct hint: I needed to install Apache POI (quite obvious, actually). Thanks

Comment: I have added the `jxls-poi-1.0.12.jar` file in the lib folder, which is the `apache-poi` file, isn't it? Or I still need to add other files?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have incompatible apache poi versions in my classpath. `jxls-poi:1.0.15` uses `poi:3.17`, while I have `poi:3.9`.

Changing poi to 3.17 fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

ok,if you use maven ,when maven build , maven could broken  excel file.

Exceptions reported by JXLS can be ambiguous,it's actually creating a excel file exception.

you can do like this:

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>template/*.*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>template/*.*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
 </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue when using maven profiles and resource filtering. It was fixed by turning off the resource filtering to your jxls excel templates.

```
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.xlsx</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `jxls` and `jxls-poi` are in your maven pom, 
Also check your template file is in your class path or not.

I encountered this problem, my code like :

```
InputStream is = JxlsTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/template.xlsx");
```

My problem is I mistyped `/template.xlsx` as `/template.xls`, jxls cannot find the template xls file, so this error thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that throughout the entire Internet there is still no answer to this question. First of all, you just need to replace `ExportExcelServlet.class.getResourceAsStream` with `FileInputStream`